# Beautiful Soap only working without headless mode?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i tried the following selenium script which works fine for me when i run i without the headless option -

```
link = f"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.get (link)
time.sleep (2)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/span/button')
time.sleep (2)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()
time.sleep (2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="tippy-21"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[5]').click()
time.sleep (2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="tippy-21"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/span/button').click()
time.sleep (2)
print("Well done - everything works fine...")
```

But when i try to run this in headless mode (toggle commentar in the third line) - i does not work and stops with this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tippy-21"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[5]"}
```

Why is that - normally the headless mode works fine for me most of the time?
Is there no way in this specific case to run this in headless mode?

Comment: Why scrape this? coinmarketcap has an API

Comment: you may try to add `options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')`

Comment: thanks @Dickson Godwin - with adding this line it really works
But why is that?

Comment: because the headless browser window is only 800x600 in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier and, as stated in the comments, use the API endpoint.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate


end_point = "https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical?id=1&convert=USD&time_start=1612656000&time_end=1617753600"
response = requests.get(end_point).json()
df = pd.DataFrame([q["quote"]["USD"] for q in response["data"]["quotes"]]).head(10)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", showindex=False))
```

Output:

```
   open     high      low    close       volume    market_cap  timestamp
-------  -------  -------  -------  -----------  ------------  ------------------------
38886.8  46203.9  38076.3  46196.5  1.01467e+11   8.60343e+11  2021-02-08T23:59:59.999Z
46185    48003.7  45167    46481.1  9.18098e+10   8.65683e+11  2021-02-09T23:59:59.999Z
46469.8  47145.6  43881.2  44918.2  8.73011e+10   8.36617e+11  2021-02-10T23:59:59.999Z
44898.7  48463.5  44187.8  47909.3  8.13889e+10   8.92365e+11  2021-02-11T23:59:59.999Z
47877    48745.7  46425    47504.9  7.6555e+10    8.84874e+11  2021-02-12T23:59:59.999Z
47491.2  48047.7  46392.3  47105.5  7.02505e+10   8.77479e+11  2021-02-13T23:59:59.999Z
47114.5  49487.6  47114.5  48717.3  7.12487e+10   9.07551e+11  2021-02-14T23:59:59.999Z
48696.5  48875.6  46347.5  47945.1  7.70699e+10   8.9321e+11   2021-02-15T23:59:59.999Z
47944.5  50341.1  47201.3  49199.9  7.70496e+10   9.16623e+11  2021-02-16T23:59:59.999Z
49207.3  52533.9  49072.4  52149    8.08205e+10   9.71612e+11  2021-02-17T23:59:59.999Z
```